# Can't find the toolbar for sorting the table of contents in alphabetical order in Arcmap!

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap

I am using ArcGIS Desctop 10.0 Service Pack3 and I'd like to sort the table of contents in alphabetical order but following [Sorting the table of contents in alphabetical order](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0104000000mr000000) I can't find the "Production TOC Manager" toolbar. Am I missing anything or do I need to activate anything?

Comment: This is part of the Production Mapping extension (http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/production-mapping). Are you authorized to use it?

Comment: I tried to download the 10.2 add-in by clicking the HERE hyperlink. It led me to ERSI login page which we have an account for. But once logged in, it says I don't have the permission to access that page. Has the page been taken down, or can I download it from another location? Advice appreciated!

Comment: @gbergman I converted your answer to a comment.  Please reserve questions or follow-ups such as these for the comment section.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Production TOC Manager toolbar is a part of the Aeronautical solutions extension or possibly some other specialized extensions which can be purchased separately.  I believe this extension also requires a Standard (formerly ArcEditor) or Advanced (formerly ArcInfo) level extension. If you have purchased these extensions, make sure to enable them in Customize--> Extensions. You should then be able to see and use the associated tools.

The only other way I know of to order items in the TOC alphabetically or otherwise is programmatically using some type of bubble sort and ArcObjects. If you have the VBA module installed you can **[try the code posted here](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/6106-sorting-layers-in-TOC-in-alphabetical-order)**.  Unfortunately, as of version 10, VBA is not global (can no longer reside in main template) and you cannot share the tool among all instances of ArcMap. (Workaround is to save the VBA tool into a document and use that particular document as a starting point for all your other document then Save As...) Instead you could create an add-in using the same code which you will be able to access from all instances of ArcMap on your machine.

EDIT: I made the VBA sample into an ArcMap 10.2 add-in.  It's a little slow with 20+ layers but it works. I tested on 60 layers and it worked fine. A-Z only. **You can download it [HERE](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=75f776babf8341c28f1d529703c80b83).**  If it works fine, please rate it.

Comment: Guess I type too slow - you beat me to it, even with the same link.  However I will add that the toolbar is part of Production Mapping in general, which is its own extension and included in several other extensions such as Aeronautical Solutions.

Comment: LOL! You could make the add-in and post it.

Comment: Oh yes, right. I am not up to speed with all those. I looked into production mapping before for some specialized cartography functions but could not justify the cost.  I believe it was in the 10K neighborhood.